# Allowing an &[impl Trait] to behave like an &[&dyn Trait]

Tags: rust, traits

Forgive in advance for the bad title. I will try to be clear in the description.

I am making an application that requires to work with `tokio_postresql` and `tiberius`.
I need to provide query parameters for both connectors. This are their signatures.

**postgresql**

```
tokio_postgres::client::Client
pub async fn query<T>(&self, statement: &T, params: &[&dyn ToSql + Sync]) -> Result<Vec<Row>, Error>
```

**tiberius**

```
tiberius::query::Query
pub fn bind(&mut self, param: impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a)
```

As you may observe, `tokio_postres` admits a reference to an array a trait objets, which is really convenient. But, my bottleneck is with the param of tiberius.

Here's my code:

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait Transaction<T: Debug> {
    /// Performs the necessary to execute a query against the database
    async fn query<'a>(stmt: String, params: &'a [&'a (dyn QueryParameters<'a> + Sync)], datasource_name: &'a str) 
        -> Result<DatabaseResult<T>, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Sync + Send + 'static)>>
    {
        let database_connection = if datasource_name == "" {
            DatabaseConnection::new(&DEFAULT_DATASOURCE.properties).await
        } else { // Get the specified one
            DatabaseConnection::new(
                &DATASOURCES.iter()
                .find( |ds| ds.name == datasource_name)
                .expect(&format!("No datasource found with the specified parameter: `{}`", datasource_name))
                .properties
            ).await
        };

        if let Err(_db_conn) = database_connection {
            todo!();
        } else {
            // No errors
            let db_conn = database_connection.ok().unwrap();
             
            match db_conn.database_type {
                DatabaseType::PostgreSql => {
                    let mut m_params: Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)> = Vec::new();
                    for p in params.iter() {
                        m_params.push(&p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync))
                    }
                    postgres_query_launcher::launch::<T>(db_conn, stmt, params).await
                },
                DatabaseType::SqlServer =>
                    sqlserver_query_launcher::launch::<T>(db_conn, stmt, params).await
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `QueryParameters`:

```
pub trait QueryParameters<'a> {}

impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for i32 {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for i64 {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for &'a str {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for String {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for &'a String {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for &'a [u8] {}

impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for &'a (dyn ToSql + Sync + Send) {}
impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for &'a dyn IntoSql<'a> {}
```

1st question:

- I want to cast the `&'a dyn QueryParameters<'a>` to `&'a (dyn ToSql + Sync)`. Is this possible to cast from some trait to another?

2nd question:

- The `.bind()` method of the `tiberius` client, only accept values that impl `IntoSql<'a>`.
  But I need to mix in my collection different values that already implements `IntoSql<'a`, but they have different type. I would like to know how to... cast??? those values of type `&'a dyn QueryParameters<'a>` to the values accepted by the function.

Are those things possible?

*NOTE*: The `launch` method from both modules are just a wrapper over the method calls provided above, but they accept as parameter `params: &'a[&'a dyn QueryParameters<'a>]`

Edit:

```
pub async fn launch<'a, T>(
        db_conn: DatabaseConnection,
        stmt: String,
        params: &'a [&'a dyn QueryParameters<'a>],
    ) -> Result<DatabaseResult<T>, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>> 
        where 
            T: Debug
    {
        let mut sql_server_query = Query::new(stmt);
        params.into_iter().for_each( |param| sql_server_query.bind( param ));

        let client: &mut Client<TcpStream> = &mut db_conn.sqlserver_connection
            .expect("Error querying the SqlServer database") // TODO Better msg
            .client;

        let _results: Vec<Row> = sql_server_query.query(client).await?
            .into_results().await?
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();

        Ok(DatabaseResult::new(vec![]))
    }
```

that's the more conflictive part for me. `.bind(impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a), so I should call this method for every parameter that I want to bind. I would like to cast ' &dyn QueryParameters<'a>` to `impl ...`, but I don't know if that's is even possible.

But, if I change the method signature to:

```
pub async fn launch<'a, T>(
        db_conn: DatabaseConnection,
        stmt: String,
        params: &'a [impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a],
    ) -> Result<DatabaseResult<T>, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>
```

I just only can accept values of the same type. Imagine a insert query, for example. I need to be flexible to accept both i32, i64, &str... depending on the column type. So this isn't valid for my case.

*Edit 2*

I've found a way to solve the `postgres` side of the issue.

```
trait AsAny {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn std::any::Any;
}
impl AsAny for i32 {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn std::any::Any {
        self
    }
}

pub trait QueryParameters<'a> {
    fn as_postgres_param(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync + 'a);
}

impl<'a> QueryParameters<'a> for i32 {
    fn as_postgres_param(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync + 'a) {
        let a: Box<&dyn AsAny> = Box::new(self);
        match a.as_any().downcast_ref::<i32>() {
            Some(b) => b,
            None => panic!("Bad conversion of parameters"),
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's elegant, or harms performance (sure it does), but I can write now:

```
let mut m_params: Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)> = Vec::new();
for param in params {
    m_params.push(param.as_postgres_param());
}

let query_result = client.query(&stmt, m_params.as_slice()).await;
```

But I can't figure out still how to work with the `impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a` of *tiberius*

Comment: I don't really understand question 2. What do you mean by "types that implemtns `IntoSql` but you cannot bind them beforehand"?

Comment: That method accepts any type that `impl IntoSql<'a>`, in order to "bind" the parameters to the query. I would need to convert the `&dyn QueryParameters<'a>` into something that fits into the `impl IntoSql<'a>`. Edited `beforehand`

Comment: Also, a way of thinking about the second question is if it's possible to (cast, convert?) the `&dyn QueryParameters<'a>` to `impl IntoSql<'a>`

Comment: I have trouble to answer you, the question is too complex it's come with too much complicated dependencies, I would guess you are doing it wrong. You probably should have a vec with your concrete type and call the two function with it instead of wanted to have something magic that work for both. You are looking for something too complex

Comment: The `IntoSql` is problematic as it is by value and can't support `dyn` directly.

Comment: Can you create a more minimal example, something we can run?

Comment: It's a large macro based codebase. I guess that the point of @Stargateur solves the half of my problem. I've already though about that, but I was trying to find a better solution. Even tho, if I choose to split both calls (one for postgres, one for tiberius), I still don't know how to pass the query parameters in a datastructure that supports i32, i64, &str,,, to be able to use the tiberius bind method. I updated the question to reflect the last problem.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I found how to solve the `postgres` side of the trait objects cast, edited to reflect it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you need a `&dyn QueryParameter` to work as both a `&dyn ToSql` and an `impl IntoSql`, right? Lets start from scratch:

```
trait QueryParameter {}
```

The `&dyn ToSql` part is easy since you can use the trick shown in [this answer](/a/55914318/2189130). You need your `QueryParameter` trait to have an associated function to convert from `&self` to `&dyn Sql`. Like so:

```
trait QueryParameter {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &dyn ToSql;
```

The `impl IntoSql` is trickier since consuming trait objects is a dicey affair. However, to implement the trait, we only need to construct a `ColumnData`. And we'll see in a second that its just that simple:

```
trait QueryParameter {
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_>;
```

because we can next implement `IntoSql` for `&dyn QueryParameter` like I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73765036/converting-trait-object-to-impl-expression):

```
impl<'a> IntoSql<'a> for &'a dyn QueryParameter {
    fn into_sql(self) -> ColumnData<'a> {
        self.as_column_data()
    }
}
```

And besides implementation for `QueryParameter` itself, that's it! We need to sprinkle in some `Sync` since `ToSql` and `IntoSql` require them, but this is a (mostly) working example:

```
use tiberius::{ColumnData, IntoSql, Query};
use tokio_postgres::types::ToSql;

trait QueryParameter: Sync {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync);
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_>;
}

impl QueryParameter for i32 {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync) { self }
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_> { ColumnData::I32(Some(*self)) }
}

impl QueryParameter for i64 {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync) { self }
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_> { ColumnData::I64(Some(*self)) }
}

impl QueryParameter for &'_ str {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync) { self }
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_> { ColumnData::String(Some((*self).into())) }
}

impl QueryParameter for String {
    fn as_to_sql(&self) -> &(dyn ToSql + Sync) { self }
    fn as_column_data(&self) -> ColumnData<'_> { ColumnData::String(Some(self.into())) }
}

impl<'a> IntoSql<'a> for &'a dyn QueryParameter {
    fn into_sql(self) -> ColumnData<'a> {
        self.as_column_data()
    }
}

async fn via_tiberius(stmt: &str, params: &[&dyn QueryParameter]) {
    let mut client: tiberius::Client<_> = todo!();
    let mut query = Query::new(stmt);
    for &param in params {
        query.bind(param)
    }
    let _ = query.execute(&mut client).await;
}

async fn via_tokio_postgres(stmt: &str, params: &[&dyn QueryParameter]) {
    let client: tokio_postgres::Client = todo!();
    let params: Vec<_> = params.iter().map(|p| p.as_to_sql()).collect();
    let _ = client.query(stmt, &params).await;
}
```

Comment: That's just perfect. I spent all my day playing with `std::any::Any`, even with `std::mem::transmute` (bad things happened), and the solution was just right in front of my eyes. I can't explain you how happy I am now. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the impl of the String, does not need `self.as_str().into`. `.into()` already performs the conversion

Comment: I just tried now the solution on the real project and works perfectly. Lot of thanks again @kmdreko