# Converting trait object to impl expression

Tags: rust, casting, traits

This question is related with this one opened previously for me, but summarizing "the big deal".

Given this:

```
pub trait TraitA {}
```

Is it possible in Rust, having a `&dyn TraitA` as argument of a function, "casting it" or convert it in some way to an `impl` expr?

Like this:

```
fn a<'a>(param: &'a dyn TraitA) {
    b( param )  // param should be converted
}
```

where `b` is a external function which has a signature like this:

```
fn b(param: impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if `&dyn TraitA` implements `IntoSql`. See here:

```
trait IntoSql<'a> {}
trait TraitA {}

impl<'a> IntoSql<'a> for &'a dyn TraitA {}

fn a<'a>(param: &'a dyn TraitA) { b(param) }
fn b<'a>(param: impl IntoSql<'a> + 'a) {}
```